# Add new property to objects in an array based of a seperate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays with objects in them.  I am trying to make a new array based on the information provided in the original 2 arrays.  I have jQuery and Underscore available.

The 2 arrays look like the following:

```
var orgArray = [
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "value": "123-456-7890"
  },
  {
    "name": "color",
    "value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "city",
    "value": "San Diego"
  },
  {
    "name": "zip",
    "value": "54321"
  },
  {
    "name": "email",
    "value": "something@somewhere.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "state",
    "value": "CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sale",
    "value": "On Sale"
  }
];

var configArray = [
  {
    "columns": ["phone", "city", "zip"],
    "target": "phone"
  },
  {
    "columns": ["email", "state"],
    "target": "email"
  }
];
```

If `configArray[i].columns` contains a string that is in `orgArray[i].name` then add the `target` property to the orgArray's object.  Here is the new Array that I am trying to create:

```
var newArray = [
  {
    "name": "phone",
    "value": "123-456-7890",
    "target": "phone"
  },
  {
    "name": "color",
    "value": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "city",
    "value": "San Diego",
    "target": "phone"
  },
  {
    "name": "zip",
    "value": "54321",
    "target": "phone"
  },
  {
    "name": "email",
    "value": "something@somewhere.com",
    "target": "email"
 },
  {
    "name": "state",
    "value": "CA",
    "target": "email"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sale",
    "value": "On Sale"
  }
];
```

Here is my current JS and a fiddle:

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9Dv2f/

```
var newArray = [];

_.each(orgArray, function(element, index, list) { 

  _.each(configArray, function(elem, i) {

    _.each(elem.columns, function (el, x) {

        if (element.name === el.name) {
            console.log(element.name);

            newArray.push({
                name: element.name,
                value: element.value,
                target: elem.target
            });

        }
    });
  });

});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: I would convert `configArray` to an object whose keys are the columns and values are the targets. Then you can simply iterate through `orgArray` and add the target when it exists, rather than having to loop through the `columns` array each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$.each()` you can do:

```
$.each(orgArray, function(i, org){
  $.each(configArray, function(j, config){
      if(config.columns.indexOf(org.name) > -1){
          orgArray[i].target = config.target;
      }
  });
});
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: Thank you!  I think I was losing track of where I was with the nested eaches and just having a hard time thinking through that.

Answer (score 1):

You should test if the name exists in elem.column, you can do this by using the [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function. The .indexOf function returns the index of the found object (starting from 0), if it isn't found it will return -1.

```
if(elem.columns.indexOf(element.name) > -1)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Dv2f/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something underscore way, not sure(didn't confirmed), should work. 
Copy the array and map it to updated based on your condition.

```
var newArray = orgArray;
_.map(newArray, function(elem){
  _.each(configArray, function(elem_config, i) {
    if(_.contains(elem_config, newArray.name)){
      return newArray['target'] = elemconfig.target
    }
  }
}
```